# Get the Exact Entry Price in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, strategy-pattern, pine-script-v5

How to get the exact entry price for the order. In TradingView Strategy Tester I see order prices are different than one captured by the strategy which leads to a wrong calculation of the stop-loss and take-profit.

```
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("MACrossLE", strategy.long, comment="LE")
    
    entryPos                                := nz(pos[1]) == 0 and longCondition

    entry_price                             := entryPos ? open : entry_price
    
    tp_level_long                           := entry_price * (1 + tpl/100)
    sl_level_long                           := entry_price * (1 - sll/100)
    
    tp_exit                                 := nz(pos[1]) == 1 and (ta.crossover(low, tp_level_long))
    sl_exit                                 := nz(pos[1]) == 1 and (ta.crossunder(high, sl_level_long))
    
    if(tp_exit)
        strategy.exit("TP-L", from_entry="EL", qty=pos, profit = tp_level_long, stop = sl_level_long)
        strategy.close("Close_L", when=tp_exit)
        
    if(sl_exit)
        strategy.cancel("Cancel_L", when=sl_exit)

    
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("MACrossSE", strategy.short, comment="SE")
    
    entryPos                                := nz(pos[1]) == 0 and shortCondition

    entry_price                             := entryPos ? open : entry_price
    
    tp_level_short                          := entry_price * (1 - tps/100)
    sl_level_short                          := entry_price * (1 + sls/100)

    tp_exit                                 := nz(pos[1]) == 1 and (ta.crossover(low, tp_level_short))
    sl_exit                                 := nz(pos[1]) == 1 and (ta.crossunder(high, sl_level_short))
    
    if(tp_exit)
        strategy.exit("TP-L", from_entry="EL", qty=pos, profit = tp_level_short, stop = sl_level_short)
        strategy.close("Close_L", when=tp_exit)
    
    if(sl_exit)
        strategy.cancel("Cancel_L", when=sl_exit)
```

When the LongCondition is met a strategy entry is open however I'm not getting the exact price, for example, I see in the Strategy Test `29340` while in the label of `entry_price` I see `29335` that's a slight difference that might affect the strategy testing.

Not I'm not using `strategy.position` to apply the same condition in the indicator if that's possible

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking at the wrong candle.

You are setting your entry price when your condition is true. However, your entry will be placed either when the bar is closed or the next bar is open.

I would remove all those calculations and assignments from the if block and put them in the global scopr. Then you can use

```
entryPrice = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
```

to get the exact entry price.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer:

In the statement defining the strategy you can set ProcessOrdersOnClose=true
The effect is that an order will be handled at(/right after) closing the candle at the close price.

Default ProcessOrdersOnClose=false is used causing the order handled at the next bar.

What is best?
If you set it 'true' indeed you're getting a price that might not be valid at the next bar.
If you set it 'false' you're waiting 1 bar, 1 day or a weekend.
Is that acceptable?

I prefer 'true' as I want the price I get (while backtesting) to be as close as possible to the price I used for submitting the order.

I found out it can make a big difference in testing if you use 'true' or 'false'.

Answer (score 0):

this code will show you the oppening price of the current canlde and it change step by step with candles

```
study("Tables", overlay=true)

// Custom function to truncate (cut) excess decimal places
truncate(_number, _decimalPlaces) =>
    _factor = pow(10, _decimalPlaces)
    int(_number * _factor) / _factor

// Get display data

mktChange = (change(close) / close[1]) * 100

// Create table
var table myTable = table.new(position.top_right, 10, 10, border_width=1)

// Update table
if barstate.islast
   
    txt2 = "Opening Price\n" + tostring(open)
    

    table.cell(myTable, 0, 1, text=txt2, bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.white)
```