# How can I add plot to a strategy alert message within Tradingview?

Tags: alert, message, tradingview-api

So I am attempting to augment a strategy alert message with a value that has been plotted on the chart. In this case, it is tightly integrated into the Strategy Tester and summons the entry price.
Essentially, I am now looking to include this price within the strategy alert message - which pops up when an alert is triggered.

So I have this at this just after the strategy.entry...

```
//BUY SELL STRATEGY
if afterStartDate == true
longCondition = Buy
if (longCondition)
strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long, alert_message = buyAlertMessage)

shortCondition = Sell
if (shortCondition)
strategy.entry("SELL", strategy.short, alert_message = sellAlertMessage)

// Get price of last entry in current position
lastEntryPrice = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)

// Display last entry price on the chart
plot(lastEntryPrice, color=color.fuchsia, style=plot.style_circles,
linewidth=3, title="Last entry price")
```

It loads on the chart nicely and does indeed pull the proper entry price. BUT, how would I then include in the strategy alert message, as it is a plot on the chart and I should be able to call it up when an alert is triggered. but none of the below is working. The last three are my attempt to get the price to be included, but all three are not working. What am I doing wrong??!!

```
{
"ticker": "{{ticker}}",
"action": "{{strategy.order.action}}",
"sentiment": "{{strategy.market_position}}",
"quantity": "{{strategy.order.contracts}}",
"{{plot("Last entry price")}}", 
"{{plot("lastEntryPrice")}}", 
"{{plot(lastEntryPrice)}}"
}
```

Here is a link to a related or relevant question: [Get the Exact Entry Price in Pine Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72624659/get-the-exact-entry-price-in-pine-script/73057915?noredirect=1#comment129033337_73057915)

Comment: "{{plot("Last entry price")}}" looks correct. But you can append `lastEntryPrice` value directly into buyAlertMessage or sellAlertMessage.

Comment: OK - thank you for your comment confirming it is looks correct. This gives me confidence that piece is right. But the second part of your comment is even better, by Including it in the sellAlertMessage/buyAlertMessage. Was not thinking to do that. I have been playing with both strategy alert options  - appears that is a stronger option anyhow.  Makes the coding of the actual alerts even easier too, as you only require {{strategy.order.alert_message}} in the message section. Thank you!